# geocode not working persistently in php

Tags: php, geocoding

```
$address = "New Delhi, Delhi, India"; //taking the address by POST, used random address here
$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
$geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY');
$output= json_decode($geocode,true);
$latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```

After this i am storing the values of longitude and latitude in my database. The problem is that it is not working sometimes(It is storing 0.00000000 in both longitude and latitude in such cases). I am facing this problem once or twice approximately in 10 times. In such cases somehow i manged to check the value of $output['status'] and it is "OK" but still it is storing 0.00000000 in the longitude and latitude fields.

i am sure that my api is valid and supports geocoding (it also hasn't exceeded the 2500 requests per day limit)

Since the code wasn't working so i tried doing this

```
$address = "New Delhi, Delhi, India";
$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
do{
  $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY');
$output= json_decode($geocode,true);
} while ($output['status']!="OK" || $output['status']!='ZERO_RESULTS');
$latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
$longitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
```

Now it's not working at all. I am getting the message "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" after some time

Comment: So, you have made sure everything on your end is working correctly. That means that it's the code at google's that's failing. Show a [mcve] of that code so we might argue about it. Anyhow, general approach is to retry on failure.

Comment: thanks for your concern @UlrichEckhardt. you are right when you say "general approach is to retry on failure" so i  wrote these two lines in a do while loop till the $output['status'] is not "OK" 

$geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=true&key=MY_API_KEY');
$output= json_decode($geocode,true);

I did this since intially i wasnt even getting OK as the status. after doing it i am getting OK but the latitude and longitude is still 0.0000000

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have updated the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: the second example is not working since you use OR instead AND, it should be $output['status'] != "OK" && $output['status'] != 'ZERO_RESULTS'

Comment: @AveriasThanks! I definitely need some sleep. btw are $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;  and  $latitude = $geo['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']; the same?

Comment: you can use object notation if you remove in json_decode() function the second parameter, so by default it will be false and json_encode will return objects. So if you use json_decode($geocode, true); you will get associative array and you have to use array notation, if you use json_decode($geocode, false); or json_decode($geocode); you will get PHP objects and you can use " $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat"